# Delete all characters before '-' Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a large Word document with many different names, such as:

```
Joe Bloggs Ltd - Joe Bloggs Limited Acc
Adam Smith Ltd - Adam Smith Limited Acc
```

There are all in tables, in separate cells.

I was wondering what the VBA code in word would be to get an output like this:

```
Joe Bloggs Limited Acc
Adam Smith Limited Acc
```

Rather than manually removing the part before the '-' each time.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit:

I have this so far that is not working:

```
Sub replaceCharToNothing()
Dim itable As Table
Dim C As Cell
Dim str1 As String
For Each itable In ThisDocument.Tables
    For Each C In itable.Range.Cells
        C.Range.Text = Left(str1, InStr(str1, "-") - 1)
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

EDIT 2.0

I now have code that works:

```
Dim myTable As Table
Dim myrow As Row
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Integer

For Each myTable In ActiveDocument.Tables
    For Each myrow In myTable.Rows
        For i = 1 To myrow.Cells.Count
                x = InStr(myrow.Cells(i).Range.Text, "-")
            If x > 0 Then
                    myrow.Cells(i).Range = Replace(Trim(Mid(myrow.Cells(i).Range.Text, x + 1)), ChrW(13), "")
            End If
        Next i
    Next myrow
Next myTable
```

Comment: `split` will do this, so `trim(split("Joe Bloggs Ltd - Joe Bloggs Limited Acc","-")(1))`

Comment: And that will work in Word? That looks like an excel formula to me, no?

Comment: You need to iterate through each table, then for each table iterate each cell, then if the text of the cell contains "Ltd -" select the part of the text upto the - plus one character and delete that text.  This is straightforward in VBA so I'm looking forward to seeing your code.

Comment: @Infernez why not try it?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I wasn't sure how apply this to every cell, rather than manually putting every different name in.

Comment: "not working" is not informative. Please describe in detail **how** it's not working.

Comment: @CindyMeister - No error was presented, it ran, but nothing happened. I am not sure how to better inform you of the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim myTable As Table
Dim myrow As Row
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Integer

For Each myTable In ActiveDocument.Tables
    For Each myrow In myTable.Rows
        For i = 1 To myrow.Cells.Count
            x = InStr(myrow.Cells(i).Range.Text, "-")
            If x > 0 Then
                myrow.Cells(i).Range = Replace(Trim(Mid(myrow.Cells(i).Range.Text, x + 1)), ChrW(13), "")
            End If
        Next i
    Next myrow
Next myTable
```